# lit element unable to render in for each loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lit-element, vaadin14, lit

I'm having an object property like so

```
pageSizeValues: {
  type: Object
}
```

that is being instantiated like this

```
this.pageSizeValues = {10: 10, 25: 25, 50: 50};
```

Based on it I'd like to build a dropdown with 3 entries, that is by iterating over the pageSizeValues

```
<vaadin-select @change="${event => this.setLimit(event.target.value)}" value="${this.limit}" placeholder="Page Size" style="width: 80px">
  <template>
    <vaadin-list-box>
      ${Object.entries(this.pageSizeValues).forEach(([key, val]) => 
          {   console.log(key + " " + val);
              html`
                <vaadin-item value=${key}>${val}</vaadin-item>
                 `
            })}
    </vaadin-list-box>
  </template>
</vaadin-select>
```

While the console.log properly display the key-value pairs in the UI I'm not getting the items rendered at all.

I managed to render the items properly when the I was iterating over an array instead of an Object so I'm not sure where the issue might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return the html value or it is just created and discarded. The easiest way is to use `map` instead of `forEach`

```
      ${Object.entries(this.pageSizeValues).map(([key, val]) => 
          {   console.log(key + " " + val);
              return html`
                <vaadin-item value=${key}>${val}</vaadin-item>
                 `
            })}
```

Comment: The entire render function returns the html value, like so:

render(){
        return html`
       <code here>`}

As I mentioned in the post, I can produce the html element when iterating over an array instead of a map / object, e.g.:
[
<vaadin-list-box>
 {this.pageSizeValues.map(item => 
  html`
   <vaadin-item value=${item}>${item}</vaadin-item>
  `)}
</vaadin-list-box>]

Comment: The code you have right now is like

`String value = "Here are the numbers";for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) { "hello" +i; } return value;`

because you are not assigning the value you create inside the loop to anything